# mysql queries so slow

Tags: mysql

It's been few days I try to figure out why the queries are so slow.
I have big table, not huge ~70,000 records, I'm making searches only on 2 fields, I set up indexes and the query takes few minutes.

These are only simple queries, nothing extending. I tried with explain select - but nothing unusual. It does not make any difference or I make searches on website or on server directly.

Any idea what can go wrong?

query is something like that

```
SELECT table3_id, email from table1 GROUP BY ID;
```

queries extends by user choices ... but this is primary search - this is slow, when expanding searches is even worse. Time differs from 34-400s.

Table looks like this:

```
Table1 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  other_id varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  flag_deleted tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  datetime datetime NOT NULL,
  table3_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  text_header varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  text_body text NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

index on: email, table3_id (on which I made searches)

Comment: Can you attach an explain plan?

Comment: Any sign of a where clause?

Comment: If this is a newer machine and you haven't manually configured your my.ini, you should probably look into that: http://blog.secaserver.com/2011/08/mysql-recommended-my-cnf-settings-innodb-engine/

Comment: @Scott Yang thanks for your suggestion - I tried to access my.fnc and there are only few settings-it is not my server, so I'll ask to make modifications.

Comment: Well, if it's a hosted server then they're probably doing something wrong. I just tried running a simple select * on my laptop (Dell Win 7), and it took less than 3 seconds for 250,000 records. Adding or removing the group by id didn't make any difference. Selecting 2 columns instead of select * took 1.2 seconds. So I don't think there is anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @ScottYang yes, it must be something wrong. On my computer worked all as on yours, but I couldn't find out - what is really wrong.Thanks for your answer .. my code was so simple, that was difficult to make it better, but server was crashing after few queries - the simplest as I could do. Found a solution, but I still think, there should be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution ...  the table contained too many unused data. After moving those data into another table, all became faster.(I know this shouldn't be the reason, but it worked)

Other possible reason to make this work better was an upgrade of mysql from 5.1 to 5.5.

I made more normalization on table and we can get results faster. (ASAP I've got the permission of doing it).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually want all ~70,000 ids/emails, there isn't a better way to do it than what you have here. Is there a smaller subset of information you could query for? If you're not using them all at once, you could try:

```
SELECT table3_id, email, FROM table1
LIMIT x
```

Where x is whatever number of entries you need.

Comment: queries from here extends - if user_id > 222 , user_id < 222, text_body like ... but this is a base search - which is used primarily, sorry - fogot to mention GROUP BY id

Comment: I don't know why you're using GROUP BY id here, each id should only have one entry associated with it. Are you sure you don't mean to be using ORDER BY?

Comment: sorry, mistyped ... I'm not seeking for id(PK) but table3_id - it is not unique, and GROUP BY option it is supposed to be faster than SELECT ... DISTINCT

Comment: unfortunately I need them all at once